# How long was Deadpool at The Workshop?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the 2016 film [*Deadpool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)), the protagonist Wade Wilson volunteers for a series of experiments at The Workshop - a facility similar to the Weapon X Program that created Wolverine. The montage of his time there led me to believe it was a few weeks, or a few months at most before his time there ended. His girlfriend, however, felt like he abandoned her since it's apparently been 2-3 YEARS since he left for the Workshop.

**How long was Deadpool with The Workshop, from the time they rolled him on a gurney to the time he & Ajax brought the house down?**

Comment: Deadpool never tried to contact her because he felt extreme shame from his deformity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Probably a few weeks**

Although there is nothing to directly reference to how long it took them to make a Super-Slave, we do get an idea at the start of the movie when we see Ajax delivering a bunch of Super-Slaves to the [Warlord](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0073088/?ref_=tt_cl_t4).

The Warlord asks about next months shipment and Ajax states that he is having a disruption to the supply chain. Now this on its own really does not say much because, lets say a disruption to supply for a 15 year old whisky would not affect anyone for another 15 years when that batch is to be sold. But Ajax says that he has to give his limited Super-Slaves to someone else, **HOWEVER**, will deliver in full the following month. So I am going to assume that it takes about a month to pump out a Super-slave.

So even though I can't say exactly how long Wade was in The Workshop himself, it was probably less than a month. Also, we are shown many of the torture methods and the longest seems to be the Oxygen tube, which seems to take a couple of days.

As to the time it takes for Wade to get into contact with his girlfriend, it was most likely about a little over a year from when Wade escaped from The Workshop to when he finally gets to talk to Vanessa.

In this scene:

> I have been waiting **one year, three weeks, six days and oh, 14 mins** to make him fix what he did to me.

So based on that the story pretty much starts in real time from the highway fight scene and it is only a few days from when Ajax finally finds out that Wade is still alive to when he kidnaps Vanessa.

So it has been approximately **one year and 3 weeks** since he escaped The Workshop.